# How to publish REST webservice with Spring?

Tags: java, spring, cxf, jax-rs

I have a `SOAP` webservice with `CXF` and publish it with `Spring` in the following way:

application-context.xml:

```
<jaxws:endpoint implementor="de.test.MyService" address="/MyService" />
```

What is the equivalent for a `REST` service?

Comment: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxrs-services-configuration.html#JAXRSServicesConfiguration-ConfiguringJAX-RSservicesusingexplicitbeanconfiguration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<jaxrs:server serviceClass="de.test.MyServiceRest" address="/MyServiceRest" />
```

Answer (score 1):

**CXF 2.7.3**

```
<bean id="restService" class="de.test.MyServiceRest" />

<jaxrs:server id="restServiceCXF" address="/MyServiceRest">
       <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
             <ref bean="restService" />
       </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
</jaxrs:server>
```

**json version**

```
    <jaxrs:server id="restServiceCXF" address="/MyServiceRest">
         <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
              <ref bean="restService" />
         </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
         <jaxrs:providers>
            <ref bean='jsonProvider' />
        </jaxrs:providers>
    </jaxrs:server>

<bean id="jsonProvider" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider"/>
```

**xml version**

```
    <jaxrs:server id="restServiceCXF" address="/MyServiceRest">
         <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
              <ref bean="restService" />
         </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
         <jaxrs:providers>
            <ref bean='jaxbProvider' />
        </jaxrs:providers>
    </jaxrs:server>

<bean id="jaxbProvider" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JAXBElementProvider"/>
```